# Update multiple rows with multiple values in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update multiple values from same column with an array of multiple values, but I am not getting exactly why the values from the same column are updated with only one value from the array.

PHP

```
$subscribers = $db->query('SELECT * FROM subscribers');
while ($subscriber = $subscribers->fetch_object()) {
  $email = $subscriber->email;
}
$pagerank_update = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pagerank_update');
$url_pr = array('1','2','3','4');
foreach ($url_pr as $url_pr_value) {
 while ($website = $pagerank_update->fetch_object()) {
  $url = $website->URL; //domain1.com...
  $pagerank = $website->CURRENT_PR; // 0
  $date = $website->PR_TODAY; // 0
  $id = $website->ID;
  //$url_pr = getpr($url);
    //var_dump($url);
        //if ($url_pr_value !== $pagerank) {
     $db->query("UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '$url_pr_value' WHERE URL = '$url'");
     $var = "UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '$url_pr_value' WHERE URL = '$url'";
     var_dump($var);
    //} else {}
 }
}
```

The `var_dump` looks in English like this:

```
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '1' WHERE URL = 'http://domain1.com'
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '1' WHERE URL = 'http://domain2.com'
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '1' WHERE URL = 'http://domain3.com'
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '1' WHERE URL = 'http://domain4.com'
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT would be

```
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '1' WHERE URL = 'http://domain1.com'
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '2' WHERE URL = 'http://domain2.com'
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '3' WHERE URL = 'http://domain3.com'
UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '4' WHERE URL = 'http://domain4.com'
```

Where am I mistaking?

Comment: its because u have two loops one outside the data fetch so if there are 4 records being selected in data fetch then the loop will have SET PR_TODAY = 1 one in the first loop.

Comment: I see, well in multiple loops, I am quite a noob.

Comment: do one thing instead of outer loop of array declare a var as `$url_pr_value = 1;` then in the data fetch loop use the update command and then do `$url_pr_value++` this should solve the problem.

Comment: The fact is that I don't want to increment the `$url_pr_value++`, that is for testing purposes, I am trying to assign different values to each urls. Function getpr() that is commented that is the function that should get different value for each url. The script is about getting the pagerank of each url and updating it as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$subscribers = $db->query('SELECT * FROM subscribers');
while ($subscriber = $subscribers->fetch_object()) {
  $email = $subscriber->email;
}
$pagerank_update = $db->query('SELECT * FROM pagerank_update');
$url_pr = array('1','2','3','4');
$i = 0;

while ($website = $pagerank_update->fetch_object()) {
  $url_pr_value = $url_pr[$i];
  $url = $website->URL; //domain1.com...
  $pagerank = $website->CURRENT_PR; // 0
  $date = $website->PR_TODAY; // 0
  $id = $website->ID;
  //$url_pr = getpr($url);
    //var_dump($url);
        //if ($url_pr_value !== $pagerank) {
     $db->query("UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '$url_pr_value' WHERE URL = '$url'");
     $var = "UPDATE pagerank_update SET PR_TODAY = '$url_pr_value' WHERE URL = '$url'";
     var_dump($var);
    //} else {}
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Now I see where am I mistaking., I did not even needed a foreach.